# Problems casting NSManagedObject to subclass type

Tags: core-data, casting, relationship, nsmanagedobject

I'm using custom classes for my CoreData stack. Class properties are set properly in the model. There's some points in the app that are abstracted to use setValue... on an NSManagedObject, but I have a few cases where that fails with an NSInvalidArgumentException, specifically when setting a related object; error indicates it wants the specific type, and it's' getting an NSManagedObject, hence the error. So, I thought I would just take the short route and cast my instance prior to the offending call, if it's of a certain entity; like this:

```
NSManagedObject *addressObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Address" inManagedObjectContext:[object managedObjectContext]];
    if ([[[object entity]name] isEqualToString:@"Hospital"]) {
        Contact *contact = (Contact*)object;
        DLog(@"The class of contact is: %@", [contact class]);
        contact.Address = addressObject;

    }
    else{
        [object setValue:addressObject forKey:@"Address"];
    }
```

I know, Address shouldn't be capitalized; I inherited this mess... anyway, I would totally expect that the contact object is a Contact, but it's not, it's an NSManagedObject! What am I doing wrong with the cast? Everything I've uncovered says this is the right way to cast, but for some reason, it's not working for me here. Of course, this wouldn't be necessary if the addressObject didn't complain about getting an NSManagedObject instead of a Contact (sorry, Hospital inherits from Contact here), and that's another baffling thing, but first things first. How can I coerce object to type Contact, which it really is?

Here's the relevant trace:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unacceptable type of value for to-one relationship: property = "Contact"; desired type = Contact; given type = NSManagedObject; value = ...

For completeness sake, the Address class has declaration for Contact as:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObject * Contact;
```

with implementation for Contact as the normal dynamic, like:

```
@dynamic Contact;
```

Maybe I need some sleep? ;-) Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cast isn't your problem. Casting doesn't change what class an object is — just what the compiler *thinks* it is.

You object is an NSManagedObject but not a `Contact` instance. In you code the `object` you have is a `Hospital` entity. Double-check that the `Hospital` entity is set to use the `Contact` class (or a subclass)).

It is important to note that Entity inheritance and Objective-C class inheritance don't have to match. I.e. you can have `Hospital` be a subentry of `Contact` and still have the `Contact` entity map to a `Contact` class without `Hospital` map to a subclass of the `Contact` class. It is valid for the `Hospital` entity to map to the (same) `Contact` class or even to `NSManagedObject` (which is what I suspect you've done).

This may seem confusing but can be very powerful if used correctly.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Hospital extends the Contact class and entity. So, if I'm not able to cast my out of this, how can I get Address to not throw the InvalidArgExc when setting it's Contact attribute using an NSManagedObject? I just assumed casting the managed object to the right type would solve it and was the quickest solution. Thanks again

Comment: Ahah!! The custom subclass wasn't added to the target... darn it; can't believe I missed that. I should have known, because whenever I've seen similar issues where a subclass of NSManagedObject is always returned as an NSManagedObject, it's either you didn't set the class property in the model, or... your class isn't in the target. dang it all;-) Thanks Daniel

Answer (score 1):

So yeah, turns out I did need some sleep;-) The problem was the subclass not being included in the target. I know I've experienced similar issues when you have a subclass, and it's in the target, but you forget to define the custom subclass in the model, too.

Comment: Thanks for returning and filling in the answer as it's just got me out of a hole! I have found that sometimes when I have (badly) resolved merge conflicts in my project file the compile directive for some classes goes missing. For an obscure reason that I haven't been able to figure out although this happened to my NSManagedObject subclass IT WAS STILL COMPILING. darn it.